# How do I get my AWS Cognito access token for updating user attributes?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the structure set up for updating user attributes, in this case the preferred username to use as an alias for signing in.

```
var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()

let prefUsername = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType();
prefUsername?.name = "preferred_username";
prefUsername?.value = usernameField.text!;
attributes.append(prefUsername!);

let attributesRequest = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderUpdateUserAttributesRequest();
attributesRequest.userAttributes = attributes;

idProvider?.updateUserAttributes(attributesRequest)
```

Only thing I have no idea how to do is get the access token. I've looked in as much documentation as I could think of but I had no luck finding place to get access token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the api to initiate auth and get an AccessToken from the AuthenticationResult.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

Answer (score 0):

```swift
    /// Function to retreive the current token for the logged in user.
    ///
    /// - Parameter completion: A completion block with an error or the token. Called back on the main thread.
    public func getJWT(completion: @escaping((_ error: Error?, _ token: AWSCognitoIdentityUserSessionToken?) -> Void)) {
        guard let user = self.pool.currentUser() else {
            let nsError = NSError(domain: "JWT Error", code: 500, userInfo: ["message": "No Logged in user"])
            completion(nsError, nil)
            return
        }
        user.getSession().continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = task.error {
                    completion(error, nil)
                }else if let token = task.result?.idToken {
                    completion(nil, token)
                }else {
                    completion(nil, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `self.pool` is the `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool` you hopefully set up correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You would have to authenticate first to establish a session with Cognito User Pools. That session would contain an access token which you can then pass to every subsequent request. I see you are using the low level SDK methods. Here is a sample in swift for SignIn:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift

Comment: and where are the tokens?